# podman with host having multiple NICs

Tags: containers, podman

using podman in rootless mode and using netavark driver , how can we specify while creating a network using podman create network as to which host interface to use . It creates a bridge but with eth0 only . If I want to use eth1 , then how can that be done ?

Tried podman network create witt --interface-name option as well ..but I don't see option to pass which physical NIC to use for podman network.